# Toolbar NavigationOnClick not work

Tags: android, navigation

Hello I have a problem with listen click on navigation icon on my toolbar:

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        myToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_48dp);
        myToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.e("navigation", "navigation");
            }
        });
```

I wrote this, but not work, it doesn't listen click and it doesn't log nothing.

Comment: View view = toolbar.getChildAt(1); 
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // Perform actions
    }
  });

Comment: also check for (0) position.

Comment: mmhh..not work..and why I should take 0 or 1 child?

Comment: setSupportActionBar(myToolbar); pick this line from above and place it after myToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListene().and let me inform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and it will work.

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Some Title");
    myToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Log.e("navigation", "navigation"); 
        }
    });
```

I think the problem is with this line " myToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_48dp);"

Edit:Tested the above code in 6.0,5.1 and it is working as expected.

Comment: Thankyou, Yes, but so I can't set a personal icon for navigation?

Comment: I tried a lot but i couldn't set the personalized icon. The code i posted will add the same ic_arrow_back_white icon. Try the code once and let me know the results.

Comment: I tried and it work, so I will open a new thread for the "custom icon" :D
thankyou